# Error re-signing and updating build number of .ipa

Tags: code-signing, ipa, info.plist

My enterprise certificate is expiring soon and I am trying to re-sign my apps. I'm taking the .ipa file and running a re-signing script. Everything works perfectly there. I can install and use the updated .ipa file as expected.

But my MDM won't accept the binary because it "already exists" so I have to update the version and/or build number. So I want to update the build number. I wrote a little script to set the build number to 42. (After I tested it in practice I was going to make it increment the number).

```
$ unzip -q myApp.ipa 
$ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion 42" Payload/myApp.app/Info.plist 
$ zip -qr myApp_done.ipa Payload
```

When I load it up into iPhone Configuration Utility it loads, but when I try to install it on a device I get "The application does not have a valid signature."

So the question is, what am I doing wrong?

Re-compiling the binaries is a last ditch option since it would involve full testing on every single app (after all, it's a new binary).

Comment: Answer coming soon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found information on one other person doing this a couple years ago.... with the exact same result. I wasn't able to get any more information than that on the Apple developer forums either.

Not 100% verified, but it seems this is impossible. You just can't update build/version numbers of a .ipa file without generating certificate errors which prevent installation.

Answer (score 0):

I've forked a project called iReSign and compiled it for you. It's fairly straightforward, and works. Let me know how it goes! https://github.com/snapapps/iReSign

Comment: Looks like that your application will re-sign the app (which I can already do), but doesn't update the CFBundleVersion number, which is causing my problem. Well, updating the number wasn't hard, but it's causing an error.